# HTML background color change based on value

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I am using a vba script to create an HTML email. It all works fine, but I need to change a background color based on a value. Below is the vba code that I have in-order to change the color `CountScoreColor`, which will be later used to create the htmlbody.

```
  CountCaseID = ![Count of Case ID+]

                  If CountCaseID >= 550 Then

                    CountScore = "Y"
                    CountScoreColor = "#8B4513"
                  Else
                        If CountCaseID >= 450 Then
                            CountScore = "Y/N"
                            CountScoreColor = "#F4A460"
                        Else
                            CountScore = "N"
                            CountScoreColor = "#87CEEB"
                        End If

                  End If
```

I am later using the CountScoreColor value in the vba htmlbody as below:

```
StrHTML = "<td width=56 nowrap valign=bottom " _style='background:CountScoreColor;width:42.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:22.5pt'>"
```

I can see it is changing the number when I debug the code, but there is no change in the background color on the email that it is creating. But if I just take the `CountScoreColor` and put let say `#87CEEB` then it changes the color.

Answer (score 1):

`CountScoreColor` is a variable, so you need to treat it as one like this:

```
_style='background:" & CountScoreColor & ";width:42.0pt;
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please remember to accept the answer so the question does not remain open.